# Sequelize: Populate the records with other table?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am new in using `PostgreSQL` and `Sequelize` in my node app ( using Hapi.js framework ).

Want to fetch all records from two tables using `Postgres` and `sequelize`:
I have two tables `Events` and `Contents` as given below:

**The eventModel.js as below:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (Sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const Events = Sequelize.define('Events', {
        id: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
        title: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.TEXT },
        createdAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
        updatedAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
    }, { timestamps: true,
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          Events.belongsTo(models.Contents, { foreignKey : ‘event’ });
        }
      }
    });
    return Events;
};
```

**And the data in Event table as:**

```
id     title              createdAt                  updatedAt

1      Event1     2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z         2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z
2      Event2     2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z         2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z
3      Event3     2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z         2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z
4      Event4     2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z         2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z
```

**The contentModel.js as below:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function (Sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const Contents = Sequelize.define(‘Contents', {
        id: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
        description: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.TEXT},
        eventId: { allowNull: false, type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
        createdAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
        updatedAt: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
    }, { timestamps: true,
      classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
          Contents.hasMany(models.Events, { foreignKey : 'id' });
        }
      }
    });
    return Contents;
};
```

**And contents having the following records:**

```
id     description     event     createdAt                        updatedAt

1      description1    1         2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z.         2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z
2     description2     1         2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z.         2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z
3     description3     2         2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z.         2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z
4     description4     2         2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z.         2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z
```

**Now I want to get the result as:**
( When I get the all records from Contents table then I want to populate particular Events according to eventID )

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        description:”description1”,
        createdAt:”2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z”,
        updatedAt:”2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z”
        eventId:{
                    id:1,
                    title:”Event1”,
                    description:”description1”,
                    createdAt:”2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z”,
                    updatedAt:”2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z”
                    }
       },
    {
        id:2,
        description:”description1”,
        createdAt:”2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z”,
        updatedAt:”2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z”
        eventId:{
                    id:1,
                    title:”Event1”,
                    description:”description1”,
                    createdAt:”2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z”,
                    updatedAt:”2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z”
                    }
       },
    {
        id:3,
        description:”description1”,
        createdAt:”2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z”,
        updatedAt:”2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z”
        eventId:{
                    id:12
                    title:”Event2”,
                    description:”description2”,
                    createdAt:”2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z”,
                    updatedAt:”2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z”
                    }
       },
    {
        id:4,
        description:”description1”,
        createdAt:”2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z”,
        updatedAt:”2019-04-10T09:50:06.481Z”
        eventId:{
                    id:12
                    title:”Event2”,
                    description:”description2”,
                    createdAt:”2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z”,
                    updatedAt:”2019-03-10T09:50:06.481Z”
                    }
       }

]
```

**To get the desire result I wrote query as below :**

```
const Models = require('./../../../models/'); // declared all models here correctly.
var getRecords= function(){
Models.Contents.findAll({ where: {},
                          include: [{ model: Models.Events, where: {} } ]
                        }).then((data) => {
                                  console.log(data);
                       });
      }
```

But I am not getting what I am looking for.

**Can anyone please suggest me where I am doing wrong and what I need to do to get the desire result ?**

Answer (score 0):

At first spot it looks like a problem with an association for `Event` model, you declare it 
like this with an explicit name for `foreignKey: 'event'`

`Events.belongsTo(models.Contents, { foreignKey : ‘event’ });`

But you are using `eventId` in your DB and `Contents` model.

You can explicity write `Events.belongsTo(models.Contents, { foreignKey : ‘eventId’ });`
or just `Events.belongsTo(models.Contents);` becouse `sequelize` by default will map to eventId as foreignKey.

Comment: Hi @Łukasz Szewczak, Thanks for your answer.

When I have added "Events.belongsTo(models. Contents);" Then getting error
"Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column Events.ContentId does not exist"

And when I have added line "Events.belongsTo(models. Contents, { foreignKey : 'eventId' });" Then getting error : "Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: column Events.eventId does not exist".

Could you help me on this ?